# Rails - Paperclip post processor unzipfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, unzip, processor

I'm trying to unzip a folder previously uploaded by paperclip.
By the time, the file is uploaded correctly, but the post processor method never called.
That's the model file:

```
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :dev_desc, :func_desc, :name, :platform, :pos_img, :repo_dir, :xib_name, :imgs, :folder

    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :platform, :presence => true
    has_attached_file   :imgs,
                    :processors => [:unzipimgs]

    has_attached_file   :folder, {
                    :styles => {:original => {:processors => [:unzipfolder]}}
                    }
end
```

And that's the lib/paperclip_processors/unzipfolder.rb file:

```
module Paperclip
class UnzipFolder < Processor

class InstanceNotGiven < ArgumentError; end

    attr_accessor :resolution, :whiny
    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super
      @file = file
      @whiny = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, File.extname(@file.path))
      @attachment = attachment
   end
   def make
      # DO THINGS HERE

   end
end
end
```

I've tryied writting the 'has_attached_file' as unzipimgs format and as unzipfolder format, but I always get **uninitialized constant Paperclip::Unzipfolder** error.

**EDIT:** Partialy fixed, the problem was with the name of the files :processors => [:unzipImgs] with a file called unzip_imgs.rb works.
The problem now is that even the make method is called, the file isn't available yet:
**File /Users/.../public/system/imgs//original/testfile.zip not found**
Why the file is not created yet?